# Installing VisualSvn to be accessible through web

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I am having troubles getting hooked into allowing other computers to grab a checkout from my computer which holds VisualSvn repository.

My url is: https://checkout:8443/svn/Repo/

Checkout = computername.

So I have only just installed VisualSvn not the instructions for Global setup are a bit unclear of what needs done to have others checkout from here. The server is in running mode, and I also can access it through that url but only on the local machine which holds the SVN.

Any information to get me going in the right direction would be helpful. The online documentation has not explained good enough for external connections.

Comment: Also: my firewalls are turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Hostname `checkout` is unknown for all other hosts in LAN. You **must** to use resolvable names in URL of your repo (or your LAN-IP).

Read "DNS for rhinos" of ask hostmaster for help

<sub>You can ask colleagues to write  `your.lan.ip checkout` into own hosts-file as last resort</sub>